CyberArk with Azure DevOps to Use Secrets in YAML Pipelines: High-level steps for beginners
I'm new to CyberArk and have a requirement to integrate it with Azure DevOps for securely managing and accessing secrets in my CI/CD pipelines. I am familiar with Azure DevOps, but not with CyberArk, so I'm looking for high-level guidance on how to start and complete this integration.
Here are my questions:

What are the initial steps required in CyberArk to prepare it for integration with Azure DevOps? For example, how do I define and load policies to authenticate Azure DevOps as a trusted workload?

Access Management: How should I grant specific Azure DevOps tasks or pipelines access to CyberArk secrets? Are there recommended policies or roles that I need to configure in CyberArk for this purpose?

Pipeline Configuration: Once CyberArk is configured, what are the best practices for accessing secrets from CyberArk within an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline? Are there specific tasks, scripts, or API calls that can be used to fetch secrets at runtime?

Parameterization: I understand that parameters like safeName and accountName might need to be referenced in the pipeline configuration. How can I ensure these are securely managed and referenced in my YAML files?

End-to-end flow: could you provide a high-level overview of the entire flow—from configuring CyberArk to retrieving secrets in Azure DevOps pipelines?


We have option of using CyberArk extension in Azure DevOps
I have gone through this document but not much clear on where to start as they have not provided any detail about extension usage.
Please provide the high level steps so that I can integrate CyberArk with Azure Devops.
note:
we use safe method to  fetch secrets not conjur service connector method

About the Parameterization question, you can use Azure DevOps secret variables or secure files to manage parameters like safeName and accountName. By the way, you can visit the CyberArk Technical Community to get more support about CyberArk.

Looks like i can not use CyberArk tech forum with gmail credentials as a learner

Hi @kumar, yes, it seems that when we registered as a Learner, allowing read-only access. If you have a customer account, you can participate in the community.
